# Windows cursor being outside of visible bounds of map using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#

What is the method to determine whether the Windows cursor is outside of the visible bounds (envelope) of the map?

I need to know if the cursor is currently over another window frame and not the map itself (i.e. the cursor is over the TOC, menus, or outside of ArcMap all together). I have used `ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.VisibleBounds` to get an `IEnvelope` and determine the visible bounds of the map, but now I need to know whether the cursor is outside of that or not.  I realize this must be a simple concept, but I have not been able to find a working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple ways:

You can get the cursor position, convert it to the map coordinates, and then compare to the active view extent.

```
IDisplayTransformation displayTransform = _map_doc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;
IPoint point = displayTransform.ToMapPoint(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
IEnvelope av_extent = _map_doc.ActiveView.Extent;
//compare point to extent bounding box
if (point.X < av_extent.XMin || point.X > av_extent.XMax ||
    point.Y < av_extent.YMin || point.Y > av_extent.YMax)
{
    //point out of bounds
}
else
{
    //point in bounds
}
```

Or you can get the ActiveView extent in screen coordinates and compare it directly to the Cursor position. This one is a touch more involved:

```
public struct Rect
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowRect(int hWnd, ref Rect rect);

public void test_cursor()
{
    Rect rect = default(Rect);
    var pt = Cursor.Position;
    GetWindowRect(_map_doc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.hWnd, ref rect);
    //compare rect bounding box to Cursor.Position
    if (pt.X < rect.Left || pt.X > rect.Right ||
        pt.Y < rect.Top || pt.Y > rect.Bottom)
    {
        //point out of bounds
    }
    else
    {
        //point in bounds
    }
}
```

The Cursor object is in System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: I have been on the track of the first suggestion.  I had the point and the extent, but I haven't been able to get any further than that.  I guess it is the "compare point to extent bounding box" where I am having the difficulty. I have tried using ITopologicalOperator, but to no good.

Comment: @DavidLewis I've updated my answer with that check. Beyond that you could also use IRelationalOperator.Disjoint() to see if the point does not intersect the active view extent.

Comment: Nice answer and very useful, never used that Cursor object, useful to know!